# H2O Deep Water on MS Azure N-Instance (GPU enabled) can not initialize backend

Tags: h2o

**Update 1:**

Log File from the H2O Deep Water Cloud: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_1g718qYsqhcUl4WFQ5S1NKbE0/view?usp=sharing

- mxnet backend - now solved (after stopping/starting the VM in Azure)
- tensorflow backend - still failure

---

I want to test H2Os Deep Water using a GPU enabled cloud instance on MS Azure (NC6 - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-n-series-general-availability-on-december-1/). **But running H2O Deep Water I got an error saying:**

- mxnet backend: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to initialize the native Deep Learning backend: Could not initialize class deepwater.backends.mxnet.MXNetBackend$MXNetLoader`
- tensorflow backend: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to initialize the native Deep Learning backend: null`

**Config and setup is as follows:**

After provisioning a DSVM on a NC6 VM. I checked the prerequisite of deep water - CUDA & CUDANN:

```
sysadmin@DEVSMTTSYGPU002:~$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Jan_10_13:22:03_CST_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.61
sysadmin@DEVSMTTSYGPU002:~$ cat /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h | grep CUDNN_MAJOR -A 2
#define CUDNN_MAJOR      5
#define CUDNN_MINOR      1
#define CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL 10
```

After that I ran the following steps:

Setup env vars:

- `export CUDA_PATH=/usr/local/cuda`
- `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$CUDA_PATH/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Install pip for python 2.7

- `sudo apt-get install python-pip`

Install Deep Water:

- `pip2 install http://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-deepwater/public/nightly/latest/h2o-3.13.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl`

Install libatlas-base-dev

- `sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev`

To run the example I start python 2.7 and run

```
import h2o
h2o.init()
```

After that I used H2O Flow to create some artificial data and learn a simple deep water model

- `createFrame {"dest":"MNIST_SIM_60k","rows":"60000","cols":"784","seed":7595850248774472000,"seed_for_column_types":-1,"randomize":true,"value":0,"real_range":100,"categorical_fraction":"0","factors":5,"integer_fraction":"1","binary_fraction":"0","binary_ones_fraction":"0","time_fraction":0,"string_fraction":0,"integer_range":"127","missing_fraction":"0","response_factors":2,"has_response":true}`
- `buildModel 'deepwater', {"model_id":"deepwater-782cc564-497c-4c39-a22a-b6904fb04188","training_frame":"MNIST_SIM_60k","nfolds":0,"response_column":"response","ignored_columns":[],"epochs":"100","ignore_const_cols":true,"network":"auto","activation":"Rectifier","hidden":[100],"problem_type":"dataset","checkpoint":"","autoencoder":false,"balance_classes":false,"score_each_iteration":false,"categorical_encoding":"AUTO","train_samples_per_iteration":-2,"standardize":true,"distribution":"AUTO","score_interval":5,"score_training_samples":10000,"score_validation_samples":0,"score_duty_cycle":0.1,"stopping_rounds":5,"stopping_metric":"AUTO","stopping_tolerance":0,"max_runtime_secs":0,"backend":"tensorflow","image_shape":[0,0],"channels":3,"network_definition_file":"","network_parameters_file":"","mean_image_file":"","export_native_parameters_prefix":"","input_dropout_ratio":0,"hidden_dropout_ratios":[],"overwrite_with_best_model":true,"target_ratio_comm_to_comp":0.05,"seed":-1,"learning_rate":0.001,"learning_rate_annealing":0.000001,"momentum_start":0.9,"momentum_ramp":10000,"momentum_stable":0.9,"classification_stop":0,"shuffle_training_data":true,"mini_batch_size":32,"clip_gradient":10,"sparse":false,"gpu":true,"device_id":[0],"cache_data":true}`

For both backends (mxnet and tensorflow) I got the errors named above. For tensorflow the stacktrace is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to initialize the native Deep Learning backend: null
    at hex.deepwater.DeepWaterModelInfo.setupNativeBackend(DeepWaterModelInfo.java:267)
    at hex.deepwater.DeepWaterModelInfo.<init>(DeepWaterModelInfo.java:214)
    at hex.deepwater.DeepWaterModel.<init>(DeepWaterModel.java:227)
    at hex.deepwater.DeepWater$DeepWaterDriver.buildModel(DeepWater.java:131)
    at hex.deepwater.DeepWater$DeepWaterDriver.computeImpl(DeepWater.java:118)
    at hex.ModelBuilder$Driver.compute2(ModelBuilder.java:173)
    at hex.deepwater.DeepWater$DeepWaterDriver.compute2(DeepWater.java:111)
    at water.H2O$H2OCountedCompleter.compute(H2O.java:1255)
    at jsr166y.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:468)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:263)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:974)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1477)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
```

And for mxnet the stacktrace is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to initialize the native Deep Learning backend: Could not initialize class deepwater.backends.mxnet.MXNetBackend$MXNetLoader
    at hex.deepwater.DeepWaterModelInfo.setupNativeBackend(DeepWaterModelInfo.java:267)
    at hex.deepwater.DeepWaterModelInfo.<init>(DeepWaterModelInfo.java:214)
    at hex.deepwater.DeepWaterModel.<init>(DeepWaterModel.java:227)
    at hex.deepwater.DeepWater$DeepWaterDriver.buildModel(DeepWater.java:131)
    at hex.deepwater.DeepWater$DeepWaterDriver.computeImpl(DeepWater.java:118)
    at hex.ModelBuilder$Driver.compute2(ModelBuilder.java:173)
    at hex.deepwater.DeepWater$DeepWaterDriver.compute2(DeepWater.java:111)
    at water.H2O$H2OCountedCompleter.compute(H2O.java:1255)
    at jsr166y.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:468)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:263)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:974)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1477)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
```

How can I get H2O Deep Water running with at least one of the backend?

Sidenote: xgboost with GPU from H2O support works.

Many thanks

Roberto

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we've ever tried running Azure except with a docker image. Are you using Ubuntu 16.04? If so it should work, unless there are differences between that and standard Ubuntu 16.04. It seems like h2o can't communicate with the backends. If you can post the full log from h2o, I could try to see what the problem could be.

Otherwise I'd say that the easiest way to run it is using the docker image, and that's what I would recommend. Everything has already been installed. The only thing you need to install is docker and nvidia-docker. Instructions: https://github.com/h2oai/deepwater#pre-release-docker-image

Comment: Comment Part I:
Thanks for the answer. 
First I checked the Ubuntu version and it is „Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-92-generic x86_64)“. I doubt that a plain Ubuntu VM from Azure use some sort of non-standard Linux version, because I never experienced any problems. But on the other side I can’t clear out that this might be some issue.

Comment: Comment Part II:
Then I made progress with the mxnet backend – it works now without changing anything. The only steps between the errors mentioned at top and the successful computation now:  I stopped the virtual VM and started it again. Maybe Azure uses some restart mechanism on the VM and this was all that was needed. I don’t know, just guessing. So, mxnet now works.
But tensorflow just has the same error then before. I attached a log file to my question.
I added the log files from H2O at the beginning of my question.

Comment: Hi, given that MXNet suddenly is working without changes, makes me thinks it's not a standard Ubuntu environment. I looked at the log files and can't say why tensorflow is not loaded. Perhaps there are some version differences on some libraries. To solve that you may need to build it yourself on that platform. Again, I would recommend you to use the docker image as we know that it works on Azure and elsewhere. https://github.com/h2oai/deepwater#pre-release-docker-image